# FOSUserBundle cant override reset password template

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I override two Fosuserbudle templates - login and register, and all works good. I put folders into `AppBundle\views\Security` and `AppBundle\views\Registration` and put there twig files for overriding.

But now I need to override the reset password template. So I created a directory with the `Resetting` name in `AppBundle\views\Resetting` and created there twig files, but I always see default template.

I cleared a cache from console, deleted folders by clicking and rebooted my computer, but nothing changed.

Comment: It should work check the name of your templates and directories. It's request and request_content right ?

Comment: @COil yes, strange, but i moved it to app/Resources/FOSUserBundle/views and now it works, i didnt want move these files to app folder, but it works...